# Codeigniter redirect() doesnt work in Opera browser

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect, header, opera

What I basically do is:

```
else
{
    // redirect to home/login
    redirect('home/login');
    return null;
}
```

It seems to work on every major browser but not in Opera. I cant find the issue. Maybe you guys know, how I can solve that? Thank you in advance.

**Soltuion**
reinstalling and resetting to default settings fixed the bug. Seems like i had some weird redirect configuration.

Comment: What happens in Opera exactly? What headers are being sent back also?

Comment: I would think content is being output before redirect() is run. If you enable error_reporting(E_ALL) in index.php, do you get an error along the lines of 'headers already sent'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Soltuion**

reinstalling and resetting to default settings fixed the bug. Seems like i had some weird redirect configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Try with PHP Header:

```
header("Location:your/site/url/home/login");
exit;
```

Comment: I modified the ans try with it

Answer (score 0):

CodeIgniter's `redirect(..)` method supports two modes of redirection (`location` which sends back a `Location:` header, and `refresh` which outputs a refresh tag).

By default (the one you're using) it uses `location`, which should work perfectly fine but only in situations where you haven't output anything to the browser previously (disregarding output buffering).

If all else fails, you can always try to use `refresh` mode like so:

```
redirect('/home/login', 'refresh');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it should work by providing full url.
**Try this :**

```
else
{
    // redirect to home/login
    redirect(base_url().'home/login');
    exit();
}
```

Comment: i tried every possibilty yesterday and today.. nothing's working, maybe i'm having some bricked opera configuration?

Comment: what is your opera version? Can you tell us that?

Comment: after reinstall it works like it should... seems like i had some weird redirect bug, i usually dont use opera as browser.. only for testing.

Answer (score 0):

The location header function in PHP requires a full absolute URL to be used. Browsers that work with a relative one are not obeying the spec, they're just doing what they do because they make assumptions about what they think you're trying to achieve.

Change the URL to an absolute one and see if that does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Use a server side redirect. For php it will look like this:

```
<?php
/* This will give an error. 
 * Note the output above, which is before the header() call */

header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
exit;
?>
```